# Python: Will not Write 'w'

Tags: python-2.7, overwrite

Python 2.7 won't overwrite existing files. It will only create new ones.

Every file that already exists named push.lua does not write changes.

```
# Push Replacer .py

import os

file_open = open('push_new.lua', 'r')
file_contents = file_open.read()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    for file in files:
        if (file == 'push.lua'):
            with open(file, 'w') as f:
                f.write(file_contents)
                f.close()
            
file_open.close()
```

Comment: what is the type of file? If it's a string, I'd guess that it is never == "push.lua". Maybe the name includes the entire path?

Comment: How is that a Lua question?

Comment: I tagged it as Lua because I wondered if Python was able to open Lua files. I thought there was a very slim chance it could be a Python + Lua issue, but now discovered it wasn't. I misunderstood how Python works.

Comment: Basically, I wasn't aware that the for file in files: if, with didn't change the directory to each file in files. 

I thought it would temporarily switch directories to whichever it was referring to, then switch back. I was wrong. Be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code always opens and overwrites `push.lua` in the current working directory, not in any subdirectory that it might a file with that name in it. You need to do `open(os.path.join(root, file), 'w')` instead of just `open(file, 'w')`.

I suspect you were trying to head in this direction with your `path` variable, but you never actually use the `path` variable for anything.

Comment: And remove “f.close()”. You’re using “with open”